# Azure DevOps query matching unassigned tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have a useful Azure DevOps (ADO) query which gives me a hierarchical view of all the active or new tasks or bugs that are assigned to me in the context of their parent user story and feature:

[image: Screen clipping of ADO Query]

I would like a near-identical query which shows unassigned bugs and tasks. How do I specify that a task is unassigned in an ADO query?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To query for unassigned items use `Assigned To = ""` (i.e. an empty value) like this:

[image: screen snip of the revised query]